# Emoji in custom Editor

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, editor

I'm working on a chat application using xamarin forms (which I am new to it), what's happening is that when I tapped on that editor box I'm not able to see emoji icon in that custom editor. How to rectify this scenario any suggestions??

[here is system control use case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8sOv.png)

[here is Custom control use case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxUSc.png)   above functionality is missing

this is the custom editor that I have used::

```
ScrollView Padding="3,2,3,2" Margin="0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
                                                <controls2:CustomEditor x:FieldModifier="Public" PlaceholderColor="LightGray" Placeholder="Type a message" AutoSize="TextChanges" x:Name="SendMessage" IsSpellCheckEnabled="True" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                                                VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Margin="0" FontSize="16" Text="{Binding SendMessageText}" Keyboard="Chat" TextColor="Black"/>
                                            </ScrollView>
```

regarding code::

```
public class CustomEditor : Editor
{
    public CustomEditor()
    {
        TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
    }
    ~CustomEditor()
    {
        TextChanged -= OnTextChanged;
    }
    private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        InvalidateMeasure();
    }
}
```

Android Editor render code::

```
public class CustomEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer
{
    public CustomEditorRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }
    [System.Obsolete]
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
        {
            GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
            gd.SetColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
            this.Control.SetBackgroundDrawable(gd);
            this.Control.SetRawInputType(InputTypes.TextFlagNoSuggestions);
            Control.Background = new ColorDrawable(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
            Control.VerticalScrollBarEnabled = false;
            Control.NestedScrollingEnabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line in your code is the reason for the emoji icon to be not shown.

```
this.Control.SetRawInputType(InputTypes.TextFlagNoSuggestions);
```

Removing the flag setting shows the Emoji. But however the No suggestion flag behaviour is lost. I tried searching the web for an alternative but could not find. Hope you find out.